# How to create Radiobuttons in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to react on a choice of a user. Something similar to this example: [image: 4 Radiobuttons]

In a 2nd stage would I like to show additional content below each radiobutton, e.g. moving the buttons 2 and 3 from each other in order to give a list of websites for allowing.

So far I haven't found how to do this in SwiftUI. 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am only learning SwiftUI and this is my first need. My first idea was to create it all from Scratch as I cannot find examples. By now I decided to go with Cocoa instead as I cannot wait too long right now. :-(

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
Picker(selection: $order.avocadoStyle, label: Text("Avocado:")) { 
    Text("Sliced").tag(AvocadoStyle.sliced) 
    Text("Mashed").tag(AvocadoStyle.mashed)
}.pickerStyle(RadioGroupPickerStyle())
```

This is the code from the 2019 swiftUI essentials keynote ([SwiftUI Essentials - WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/216/https://). Around 43 minutes in the video they show this example.

It will look like this:

[image: radio button group]

Comment: How to Create .radioGroup?

Comment: It’s a predefined type but it could be renamed to RadioGroupPickerStyle.   
`.pickerStyle(RadioGroupPickerStyle()) `

Comment: 'RadioGroupPickerStyle' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (SwiftUI.RadioGroupPickerStyle)

I am getting above error

Comment: I think radio buttons are not natively supported for iOS.

Comment: Please note that RadioGroupPickerStyle is supported on Mac only (so no iOS)

Answer (score 46):

check this out...an easy to use SwiftUI RadiobuttonGroup for iOS

you can use it like this:

```
RadioButtonGroup(items: ["Rome", "London", "Paris", "Berlin", "New York"], selectedId: "London") { selected in
                print("Selected is: \(selected)")
            }
```

and here is the code:

```
struct ColorInvert: ViewModifier {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if colorScheme == .dark {
                content.colorInvert()
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RadioButton: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    let id: String
    let callback: (String)->()
    let selectedID : String
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let textSize: CGFloat

    init(
        _ id: String,
        callback: @escaping (String)->(),
        selectedID: String,
        size: CGFloat = 20,
        color: Color = Color.primary,
        textSize: CGFloat = 14
        ) {
        self.id = id
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.textSize = textSize
        self.selectedID = selectedID
        self.callback = callback
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.callback(self.id)
        }) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Image(systemName: self.selectedID == self.id ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: self.size, height: self.size)
                    .modifier(ColorInvert())
                Text(id)
                    .font(Font.system(size: textSize))
                Spacer()
            }.foregroundColor(self.color)
        }
        .foregroundColor(self.color)
    }
}

struct RadioButtonGroup: View {

    let items : [String]

    @State var selectedId: String = ""

    let callback: (String) -> ()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
                RadioButton(self.items[index], callback: self.radioGroupCallback, selectedID: self.selectedId)
            }
        }
    }

    func radioGroupCallback(id: String) {
        selectedId = id
        callback(id)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Example")
                .font(Font.headline)
                .padding()
            RadioButtonGroup(items: ["Rome", "London", "Paris", "Berlin", "New York"], selectedId: "London") { selected in
                print("Selected is: \(selected)")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ContentViewDark_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        .darkModeFix()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer!  For my implementation I found it useful to use \@Binding for the selectedId, then I could use a \@State var in my app to hold the selectedId and pass it to the RadioButton group to be kept in sync.

Answer (score 12):

I just edited @LizJ answer , by adding `Binding` instead of `didTapActive` & `didTapInactive` , so like that it will looks like other `SwiftUI` elements

```
import SwiftUI
struct RadioButton: View {
    @Binding var checked: Bool    //the variable that determines if its checked
    
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            if checked {
                ZStack{
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
                }.onTapGesture {self.checked = false}
            } else {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    .onTapGesture {self.checked = true}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm using swift4, Catalina OS and Xcode 11.2 and was having the issue where RadioGroupPickerStyle was unavailable for iOS and .radiogroup just didn't work (it froze in build) so I made my own that's reusable for other occasions. (notice its only the button so you have to handle the logic yourself.) Hope it helps!

```
import SwiftUI

struct RadioButton: View {
let ifVariable: Bool    //the variable that determines if its checked
let onTapToActive: ()-> Void//action when taped to activate
let onTapToInactive: ()-> Void //action when taped to inactivate

var body: some View {
    Group{
        if ifVariable {
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
            }.onTapGesture {self.onTapToInactive()}
        } else {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                .onTapGesture {self.onTapToActive()}
        }
    }
}
}
```

TO USE: Put this in any file and you can use it as you would any other view anywhere else in the project. (we keep a global folder that has a buttons file in it)

Answer (score 1):

I will use the previous answer of @LizJ and i will add a text after the radio button to resemble (RadioListTile in Flutter)

```
struct RadioButton: View {
    let ifVariable: Bool    //the variable that determines if its checked
    let radioTitle: String
    var onTapToActive: ()-> Void//action when taped to activate
    let onTapToInactive: ()-> Void //action when taped to inactivate
    
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            if ifVariable {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                    ZStack{
                    Circle()
                            .fill(AppColors.primaryColor)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
                }.onTapGesture {self.onTapToInactive()}
                Text(radioTitle)
                .font(.headline)        
                }
            } else {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16){
                    Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    .onTapGesture {self.onTapToActive()}
                    
           Text(radioTitle)
           .font(.headline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I will also provide an example for the selection logic
we will create a enum for radio cases

```
enum PaymentMethod: Int {
case undefined = 0
case credit = 1
case cash  = 2
}
```

then we will create `@State` variable to carry the selection, i will not recreate another SwiftUI view but only explain the basic concept without any `boilerplate code`

```
struct YourView: View {

    @State private var paymentMethod: PaymentMethod
    
    var body: some View {
    
    RadioButton(ifVariable: paymentMethod == PaymentMethod.credit,radioTitle: "Pay in Credit",  onTapToActive: {
                        paymentMethod = .credit
                    }, onTapToInactive: {})
    
    RadioButton(ifVariable: paymentMethod == PaymentMethod.cash,radioTitle: "Pay in Cash",  onTapToActive: {
                        paymentMethod = .cash
                    }, onTapToInactive: {})
    
    
        }
    }
```

with this previous code you can toggle between radio buttons in `SwiftUI` with a text after each selection to resemble (RadioListTile in Flutter)

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a swift package to handle the missing radio button view. Thanks to @LizJ for the starting idea!

Should be easy to use, especially with enums!

[RadioButton](https://github.com/lukluca/RadioButton)