# SwiftUI: How to implement Radio button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a simple form app. In that, I have checkboxes and Radio buttons, but I don't know how to do it.

I have done below code to dynamically change the selected option's colour. But it can be select multiple values. I need to select only one value among 5 values like a radio button.

E.g:
I'm taping on the second radio button. Now if I select the fourth radio button, the second one should deselect and the fourth one should get selected.

```
struct DCTableCell: View {

    @Binding var dcValue: String

    @State var isSelected: Bool = false

    var body: some View {


        Button(action: {
            print("Tapped")
            self.isSelected.toggle()
        }){
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .stroke(self.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected"): Color.init("border"))
                    .frame(height: 56)
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)

                HStack {
                    Text(dcValue)
                        .font(.custom("Montserrat", size: 16))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(self.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected") : .white)
                        .padding()

                    Spacer()

                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(self.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected") : Color("circleBorder"))
                            .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                            .padding()

                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(self.isSelected ? Color.init("borderSelected"): Color.clear)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create Radiobuttons in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58580027/how-to-create-radiobuttons-in-swiftui)

Comment: @Andrew This is not working for me. Getting below error

--- 'RadioGroupPickerStyle' is unavailable in iOS ---

Comment: @JeevaTamil So the radioGroup is ugly on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

check this out...an easy to use SwiftUI RadiobuttonGroup for iOS

you can use it like this:

```
RadioButtonGroup(items: ["Rome", "London", "Paris", "Berlin", "New York"], selectedId: "London") { selected in
                print("Selected is: \(selected)")
            }
```

and here is the code:

```
struct ColorInvert: ViewModifier {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if colorScheme == .dark {
                content.colorInvert()
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RadioButton: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    let id: String
    let callback: (String)->()
    let selectedID : String
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let textSize: CGFloat

    init(
        _ id: String,
        callback: @escaping (String)->(),
        selectedID: String,
        size: CGFloat = 20,
        color: Color = Color.primary,
        textSize: CGFloat = 14
        ) {
        self.id = id
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.textSize = textSize
        self.selectedID = selectedID
        self.callback = callback
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.callback(self.id)
        }) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Image(systemName: self.selectedID == self.id ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: self.size, height: self.size)
                    .modifier(ColorInvert())
                Text(id)
                    .font(Font.system(size: textSize))
                Spacer()
            }.foregroundColor(self.color)
        }
        .foregroundColor(self.color)
    }
}

struct RadioButtonGroup: View {

    let items : [String]

    @State var selectedId: String = ""

    let callback: (String) -> ()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
                RadioButton(self.items[index], callback: self.radioGroupCallback, selectedID: self.selectedId)
            }
        }
    }

    func radioGroupCallback(id: String) {
        selectedId = id
        callback(id)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Example")
                .font(Font.headline)
                .padding()
            RadioButtonGroup(items: ["Rome", "London", "Paris", "Berlin", "New York"], selectedId: "London") { selected in
                print("Selected is: \(selected)")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ContentViewDark_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        .darkModeFix()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked pretty well, but when I stuck it inside a List it began selecting all buttons until it got to the end. After a day of fiddling around, I discovered it was the List causing the issue. Inside a ForEach or alone it work fine. I didn't investigate further, just a FYI for the next person.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another offering, which is perhaps simpler than the other solutions already provided.

- It can be used in connection with any kind of selection.
- With the styling provided here, the button has the same appearance as the buttons used for light/dark mode in the iOS device settings.
- The button grows larger when the user chooses to use larger fonts. This is by virtue of the `@ScaledMetric` property wrappers.

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// An indicator for showing when an item is selected
struct SelectionIndicator: View {

    /// The size for the indicator
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) private var size: CGFloat = 20

    /// The line width for stroking the unselected indicator
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) private var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.5

    /// Flag that determines whether the indicator is shown as
    /// selected (true) or not (false)
    private let isSelected: Bool

    /// Creates an indicator to reflect the supplied state.
    /// No gesture handlers are added here. For this reason,
    /// no bindings need to be supplied (the value is
    /// read-only, it is not updated here).
    init(isSelected: Bool) {
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }

    var body: some View {
        if isSelected {

            // Show a round shape with a transparent tick
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: size + lineWidth, height: size + lineWidth)
        } else {

            // Just show an empty ring
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: lineWidth)
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.tertiaryLabel))
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .padding(lineWidth / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    enum City: String, CaseIterable {
        case Rome = "Rome"
        case London = "London"
        case Paris = "Paris"
        case Berlin = "Berlin"
        case NewYork = "New York"
    }

    @State private var city = City.London

    private func radioButtonItem(choice: City) -> some View {
        HStack {
            SelectionIndicator(isSelected: city == choice)
            Text(choice.rawValue)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation { city = choice }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(City.allCases, id: \.self) { city in
                radioButtonItem(choice: city)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not an ideal solution but it works and hopefully opens your eyes to improve what you have. I give every RadioButton an ID and when the selected ID changes it updates:

```
struct DCTableCell: View {

    var id: Int
    @Binding var dcValue: String
    @Binding var selectedID: Int

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Tapped")
            self.selectedID = self.id
        }){
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .stroke(self.id == self.selectedID ? Color.blue : Color.white)
                    .frame(height: 56)
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)

                HStack {
                    Text(dcValue)
                        .font(.custom("Montserrat", size: 16))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(self.id == self.selectedID ? .blue : .white)
                        .padding()

                    Spacer()

                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(self.id == self.selectedID ? Color.blue : .black)
                            .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                            .padding()

                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(self.id == self.selectedID ? Color.blue: Color.clear)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here how to use it. maybe you should create an array with ids and the strings that you want to pass in.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var str = "lolz"
    @State var selectedID = -1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach((1...5), id: \.self) { index in
                DCTableCell(id: index, dcValue: self.$str, selectedID: self.$selectedID)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution, use the labels as the hashable tag which makes it very straight. So you only need to setting the outer layer: `CustomDCPicker`, like a general picker.

```
                 UIHostingController(rootView: CustomDCPicker())

        struct CustomDCPicker: View {
            @State var dcValue: String = ""
            var body: some View {
                VStack{
                    Text(dcValue).bold()
                    DCTable.init(dcValue: $dcValue, Labels: ["sample1","sample2","sample3","sample4","sample5"])
                }
            }
        }

        struct DCTable: View {
            @Binding var dcValue: String
            var Labels: [String] = []
        var body: some View {
            ForEach(Labels, id:\.self){
                DCTableCell(dcValue: self.$dcValue, myLabel: $0)
            }
        }
        }

        struct DCTableCell: View {
            @Binding var dcValue: String
            var isSelected: Bool {
                get{   self.dcValue == self.myLabel}
            }
            var myLabel : String
            var body: some View {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Tapped")
                    self.dcValue = self.myLabel
                }){
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8.0)
                            .stroke(self.isSelected ? Color.red: Color.yellow)
                            .frame(height: 56)
                            .foregroundColor(.clear)

                        HStack {
                            Text(myLabel)
                                //.font(.custom("Montserrat", size: 16))
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .foregroundColor(self.isSelected ? Color.red : .black)
                                .padding()

                            Spacer()

                            ZStack {
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(self.isSelected ? Color.red : Color.black)
                                    .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                                    .padding()

                                Circle()
                                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                                    .foregroundColor(self.isSelected ? Color.red: Color.clear)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```