# I need some help for the logic of a small SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, swiftui, switch-statement

I have a view with 3 switches and 1 button. At first, all the switches are false and you can only make one true. Also, the button only works if there's a difference between `customOption` and `newCustomOption`.

On the 4 scenarios possible, only 2 works with my current code :

1- You start with all the switches on `false`, make one `true` and confirm. OK

2- You start with only one switch on `true`, make it `false` and confirm. OK

3- You start with all the switches on `false`, make one `true`, make another one `true` and you get `None` instead on the correspondant value. NOT OK

4- Like the 3 but you already have one switch on `true`. NOT OK

I've discovered the problem: `newCustomOption` is set to `None` after getting the right value and not the reverse but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @AppStorage("customOption") private var customOption = "None"
    @State private var newCustomOption = "None"
    @State private var optionOne = false
    @State private var optionTwo = false
    @State private var optionThree = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Option One", isOn: $optionOne)
                .onAppear { load() }
                .onChange(of: optionOne) { _ in
                    newCustomOption = optionOne ? "optionOne" : "None"
                    print(newCustomOption)
                    if optionOne {
                        optionTwo = false
                        optionThree = false
                    }
                }
            Toggle("Option Two", isOn: $optionTwo)
                .onChange(of: optionTwo) { _ in
                    newCustomOption = optionTwo ? "optionTwo" : "None"
                    print(newCustomOption)
                    if optionTwo {
                        optionOne = false
                        optionThree = false
                    }
                }
            Toggle("Option Three", isOn: $optionThree)
                .onChange(of: optionThree) { _ in
                    newCustomOption = optionThree ? "optionThree" : "None"
                    print(newCustomOption)
                    if optionThree {
                        optionOne = false
                        optionTwo = false
                    }
                }
            Button("Confirm", action: { confirm() })
                .opacity(customOption == newCustomOption ? 0.5 : 1)
                .disabled((customOption == newCustomOption ? true : false))
        }
    }

    private func load() {
        newCustomOption = customOption
        switch newCustomOption {
        case "optionOne":
            optionOne = true
        case "optionTwo":
            optionTwo = true
        case "optionThree":
            optionThree = true
        default /* "None" */:
            return
        }
    }

    private func confirm() {
        customOption = newCustomOption
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: I would suggest using radio buttons instead of toggles. See [SwiftUI: How to implement Radio button in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75856182/20386264) for a way to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a `Picker` instead and style it as a radio button group, it will require much less code and simpler logic

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @AppStorage("customOption") private var customOption = "None"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $customOption, label: Text("Option:")) {
                Text("One").tag("optionOne")
                Text("Two").tag("optionTwo")
                Text("Three").tag("optionThree")
                Text("None").tag("None")
            }.pickerStyle(RadioGroupPickerStyle())

            Button("Dismiss") { dismiss() }
        }
    }
}
```

——

And here is an alternative solution without the “None” option

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @AppStorage("customOption") private var customOption: String = "None"
    @State private var selectedOption: String = "None"

    var body: some View {
        VStack { 

            Picker(selection: $selectedOption, label: Text("Option:")) {
                Text("One").tag("optionOne")
                Text("Two").tag("optionTwo")
                Text("Three").tag("optionThree")
            }.pickerStyle(RadioGroupPickerStyle())

            Button("Dismiss") {
                customOption = selectedOption
                dismiss()
            }
                .disabled(selectedOption == "None")
        }
        .onAppear { selectedOption = customOption }
    } 

}
```

——

A next step would be to use an enum instead to hold the different options.

Comment: Yes, I know but I really don't want to have `None` as an option. I will persevere but if I haven't found any solution I will have to use the "Radio picker" option.

Comment: Maybe you should make it a little more clear in your question that you don't want "None".

Comment: I have modified my answer to not include "None" as an option

Comment: Actually, your previous solution was the best. I have no other choice than using a `Picker` with a `None` option. But the best would be to use `.pickerStyle(.inline)` or an equivalent to get something like in the "History" of Safari. Thanks, I'll try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested as a comment that you implement using radio buttons instead of toggles. If you are targeting macOS only then you can use a `RadioGroupPickerStyle` (see other answer), but for iOS you would need to implement a different way.

Here is how it can be done using the `SelectionIndicator` to be found in the answer to [SwiftUI: How to implement Radio button in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75856182/20386264) (it was my answer).

- It starts off with no option selected (= none).
- Once an option has been selected, it is possible to change the selection, but it is not possible to go back to no selection.
- The possible options are defined by the enum `CustomOption`. You could do it all with strings if you prefer, but I would suggest that an enum is cleaner if the options are all pre-defined (for a start, there is no chance of errors being caused by typos).

```swift
enum CustomOption: String {
    case none = "None"
    case one = "optionOne"
    case two = "optionTwo"
    case three = "optionThree"
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @AppStorage("customOption") private var customOption = CustomOption.none.rawValue
    @State private var newCustomOption = CustomOption.none

    private func radioButtonItem(label: String, choice: CustomOption) -> some View {
        HStack {

            // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75856182/20386264
            SelectionIndicator(isSelected: newCustomOption == choice)
            Text(label)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation { newCustomOption = choice }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            radioButtonItem(label: "Option One", choice: .one)
            radioButtonItem(label: "Option Two", choice: .two)
            radioButtonItem(label: "Option Three", choice: .three)
            Button("Confirm", action: { confirm() })
                .opacity(newCustomOption.rawValue == customOption || newCustomOption == .none ? 0.5 : 1)
                .disabled(newCustomOption.rawValue == customOption || newCustomOption == .none)
        }
        .onAppear { load() }
    }

    private func load() {
        newCustomOption = CustomOption(rawValue: customOption) ?? .none
    }

    private func confirm() {
        customOption = newCustomOption.rawValue
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out tomorrow.