# Disable button based on checkbox values in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In UI, I should have checkboxes and button. The number of checkboxes is dependent on API. When all checkboxes are checked, the button has to be enabled.

I have viewModels and models like below. This is a high level example. The hierarchy is fixed.

```
class viewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var cars : [Cars]
}
class Cars {
@Published var bmw : [Bmw]
}
class Bmw {
@Published var isSelected = false
var carName = ""

init() {
...
}
}
```

The number of Bmw items is dependent on API. I have created checkbox in SwiftUI like below because the count is dynamic

"made a subview with one checkbox and one @State var, so each checkbox has its "own" state."

Now how do I disable the button based on checkbox value.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would consider using a computed variable that becomes true when they are all checked, and then toggle `.disabled()` on that.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. What have you tried? What part of it didn't work?

Comment: Nested ObservableObjects are going to be an uphill battle here. Any chance you can use a struct for your models?

Answer (score 0):

map your data to list of Items like this

```
struct MyItem {
    var content: String // the info of your data
    var checked: Bool
}
```

then use it for your view like this

```
struct CheckAllBoxToApplyButtonView: View {
    @Binding var items: [MyItem]
    var commit: ()->()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // the button that only active when all items are checked
            Button(action: commit) {
                Text("All Checked")
            }
            .disabled(!items.allSatisfy { $0.checked == true })
            
            // checkbox for all items
            ForEach(items.indices, id:\.self) { i in
                Toggle(items[i].content, isOn: $items[i].checked)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

check out [How can I create a text with Checkbox in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425829/how-can-i-create-a-text-with-checkbox-in-swiftui) if you want your toggle has checkbox UI style

Note: I recommend you to map your data into something like `MyItem` to separate your `Model` from your `View`, your View shouldn't know anything about `car` or `bmw` but rather what to display and what to response when user interacts it